# OpenGL big "structured" buffer

Tags: opengl, glsl

I need to access a one dimensional big(~2MB) buffer from a shader. However, I don't know which type of OpenGL buffer I should use. I'm going to store floats(16F) and unsigned integers (16UI). My data will be like an struct:

```
struct{
    float d; //16F
    int  a[7]; //or a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7; //7x16UI
}
```

I read about buffer texture and other kind of buffers([Passing a list of values to fragment shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954927/glsl-passing-a-list-of-values-to-fragment-shader)), but it only works for one type of data (float or int), not both. I could use two buffers, but I think this won't be cache friendly nor easy.

Comment: Have a look at [Shader Storage Buffer Objects (SSBO)](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_storage_buffer_object.txt). They are core since 4.0 and should do exactly what you need.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: You're going to have a bit of trouble here if you're really and truly trying to use a half-float format (16F). You are going to have to resort to things like `unpackHalf2x16` because `float` in GLSL is 32-bit (as is `int`).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that... That reminds me that I need to pack them on the CPU side, I was looking for C(not C++) libraries, I only found [this](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/07/update-19-july-06-added.html) one, that will work, right?

Comment: @dv1729: Yes, that should work. I've actually never bothered to deal with this exclusively in C. Most people use GLM for this, but I can see why you wouldn't want to use a templated C++ library in a C project :P