# A crossplatform way to render particle system using 1D texture?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Im trying to use a 1D texture from `Opengl` to fill it with the position of the particles to be rendred by the shader . I have no i idea how to do it , can someone tell me ( or give me a code example in `C/C++` / `glsl-glsl-es` ) how to define a 1D texture with the reqiured properities and how to fill it with a float array and how to use it from the shader .

Comment: Why are you using a 1D texture as the source for particle positions, instead of vertex attributes?

Comment: because i will send an array of positions to the shaders , i will compile it on android ( trying to target all gles versions) , and mainly im doing this method because that is what i have been told from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954927/glsl-passing-a-list-of-values-to-fragment-shader# , or should i do something else ?

Comment: That was a question about sending arrays to *fragment shaders*. The positions of particles are processed by *vertex shaders*. You have access to vertex attributes in a vertex shader. Why would you not simply pass the positions as [per-vertex data](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification)?

Comment: dude im the asking here , just tell me how hh XD

Comment: note im using opengl 4 on desktop & gles 2.x on android

Comment: i understand what u mean , i thought that i have to use the fragment shader by drawing circle in each particle's position , by computing the distance between the current fragment and the each particle and if it is less than particle_size i put a color if not i leave it blank and i have to do that to all screen fragments , any better method ?

Comment: Yes, e.g. render a point sprite for each particle.

Comment: thank you , i found that on google , but no details , where can i find an example or a tutorial plz