# Optimizing performance of a fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

Friends,

I need help optimizing the following fragment shader: It looks long, but actually not. It initializes a long array that contains 256 elements.

Fragment:

```
#version 410
//#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack : enable

layout (location = 0) in vec3 colorOut;

uniform int colorBands;
uniform int computeDiff;
uniform float diffScaling;
uniform sampler2D textureD;

//layout (location = 0) out vec4 colorOut;
out vec4 fColor;

vec3 computePlasmaColormap(float value, vec3 p[256]) {
  return p[int(255 * clamp(value, 0, 1))];
}

float computeColorDistance() {
  vec2 texSize;
  texSize = textureSize(textureD, 0);
  vec3 texColor = texture(textureD, gl_FragCoord.xy / texSize).xyz;
  return texColor == vec3(0) ? 0 : length(colorOut - texColor);
}

void main() {
    vec3 plasmaColormap[256];

    plasmaColormap[0]=vec3(0.050383, 0.029803, 0.527975);
    plasmaColormap[1]=vec3(0.063536, 0.028426, 0.533124);
    plasmaColormap[2]=vec3(0.075353, 0.027206, 0.538007);
    plasmaColormap[3]=vec3(0.086222, 0.026125, 0.542658);
    plasmaColormap[4]=vec3(0.096379, 0.025165, 0.547103);
    plasmaColormap[5]=vec3(0.10598, 0.024309, 0.551368);
    plasmaColormap[6]=vec3(0.115124, 0.023556, 0.555468);
    plasmaColormap[7]=vec3(0.123903, 0.022878, 0.559423);
    plasmaColormap[8]=vec3(0.132381, 0.022258, 0.56325);
    plasmaColormap[9]=vec3(0.140603, 0.021687, 0.566959);
    plasmaColormap[10]=vec3(0.148607, 0.021154, 0.570562);
    plasmaColormap[11]=vec3(0.156421, 0.020651, 0.574065);
    plasmaColormap[12]=vec3(0.16407, 0.020171, 0.577478);
    plasmaColormap[13]=vec3(0.171574, 0.019706, 0.580806);
    plasmaColormap[14]=vec3(0.17895, 0.019252, 0.584054);
    plasmaColormap[15]=vec3(0.186213, 0.018803, 0.587228);
    plasmaColormap[16]=vec3(0.193374, 0.018354, 0.59033);
    plasmaColormap[17]=vec3(0.200445, 0.017902, 0.593364);
    plasmaColormap[18]=vec3(0.207435, 0.017442, 0.596333);
    plasmaColormap[19]=vec3(0.21435, 0.016973, 0.599239);
    plasmaColormap[20]=vec3(0.221197, 0.016497, 0.602083);
    plasmaColormap[21]=vec3(0.227983, 0.016007, 0.604867);
    plasmaColormap[22]=vec3(0.234715, 0.015502, 0.607592);
    plasmaColormap[23]=vec3(0.241396, 0.014979, 0.610259);
    plasmaColormap[24]=vec3(0.248032, 0.014439, 0.612868);
    plasmaColormap[25]=vec3(0.254627, 0.013882, 0.615419);
    plasmaColormap[26]=vec3(0.261183, 0.013308, 0.617911);
    plasmaColormap[27]=vec3(0.267703, 0.012716, 0.620346);
    plasmaColormap[28]=vec3(0.274191, 0.012109, 0.622722);
    plasmaColormap[29]=vec3(0.280648, 0.011488, 0.625038);
    plasmaColormap[30]=vec3(0.287076, 0.010855, 0.627295);
    plasmaColormap[31]=vec3(0.293478, 0.010213, 0.62949);
    plasmaColormap[32]=vec3(0.299855, 0.009561, 0.631624);
    plasmaColormap[33]=vec3(0.30621, 0.008902, 0.633694);
    plasmaColormap[34]=vec3(0.312543, 0.008239, 0.6357);
    plasmaColormap[35]=vec3(0.318856, 0.007576, 0.63764);
    plasmaColormap[36]=vec3(0.32515, 0.006915, 0.639512);
    plasmaColormap[37]=vec3(0.331426, 0.006261, 0.641316);
    plasmaColormap[38]=vec3(0.337683, 0.005618, 0.643049);
    plasmaColormap[39]=vec3(0.343925, 0.004991, 0.64471);
    plasmaColormap[40]=vec3(0.35015, 0.004382, 0.646298);
    plasmaColormap[41]=vec3(0.356359, 0.003798, 0.64781);
    plasmaColormap[42]=vec3(0.362553, 0.003243, 0.649245);
    plasmaColormap[43]=vec3(0.368733, 0.002724, 0.650601);
    plasmaColormap[44]=vec3(0.374897, 0.002245, 0.651876);
    plasmaColormap[45]=vec3(0.381047, 0.001814, 0.653068);
    plasmaColormap[46]=vec3(0.387183, 0.001434, 0.654177);
    plasmaColormap[47]=vec3(0.393304, 0.001114, 0.655199);
    plasmaColormap[48]=vec3(0.399411, 0.000859, 0.656133);
    plasmaColormap[49]=vec3(0.405503, 0.000678, 0.656977);
    plasmaColormap[50]=vec3(0.41158, 0.000577, 0.65773);
    plasmaColormap[51]=vec3(0.417642, 0.000564, 0.65839);
    plasmaColormap[52]=vec3(0.423689, 0.000646, 0.658956);
    plasmaColormap[53]=vec3(0.429719, 0.000831, 0.659425);
    plasmaColormap[54]=vec3(0.435734, 0.001127, 0.659797);
    plasmaColormap[55]=vec3(0.441732, 0.00154, 0.660069);
    plasmaColormap[56]=vec3(0.447714, 0.00208, 0.66024);
    plasmaColormap[57]=vec3(0.453677, 0.002755, 0.66031);
    plasmaColormap[58]=vec3(0.459623, 0.003574, 0.660277);
    plasmaColormap[59]=vec3(0.46555, 0.004545, 0.660139);
    plasmaColormap[60]=vec3(0.471457, 0.005678, 0.659897);
    plasmaColormap[61]=vec3(0.477344, 0.00698, 0.659549);
    plasmaColormap[62]=vec3(0.48321, 0.00846, 0.659095);
    plasmaColormap[63]=vec3(0.489055, 0.010127, 0.658534);
    plasmaColormap[64]=vec3(0.494877, 0.01199, 0.657865);
    plasmaColormap[65]=vec3(0.500678, 0.014055, 0.657088);
    plasmaColormap[66]=vec3(0.506454, 0.016333, 0.656202);
    plasmaColormap[67]=vec3(0.512206, 0.018833, 0.655209);
    plasmaColormap[68]=vec3(0.517933, 0.021563, 0.654109);
    plasmaColormap[69]=vec3(0.523633, 0.024532, 0.652901);
    plasmaColormap[70]=vec3(0.529306, 0.027747, 0.651586);
    plasmaColormap[71]=vec3(0.534952, 0.031217, 0.650165);
    plasmaColormap[72]=vec3(0.54057, 0.03495, 0.64864);
    plasmaColormap[73]=vec3(0.546157, 0.038954, 0.64701);
    plasmaColormap[74]=vec3(0.551715, 0.043136, 0.645277);
    plasmaColormap[75]=vec3(0.557243, 0.047331, 0.643443);
    plasmaColormap[76]=vec3(0.562738, 0.051545, 0.641509);
    plasmaColormap[77]=vec3(0.568201, 0.055778, 0.639477);
    plasmaColormap[78]=vec3(0.573632, 0.060028, 0.637349);
    plasmaColormap[79]=vec3(0.579029, 0.064296, 0.635126);
    plasmaColormap[80]=vec3(0.584391, 0.068579, 0.632812);
    plasmaColormap[81]=vec3(0.589719, 0.072878, 0.630408);
    plasmaColormap[82]=vec3(0.595011, 0.07719, 0.627917);
    plasmaColormap[83]=vec3(0.600266, 0.081516, 0.625342);
    plasmaColormap[84]=vec3(0.605485, 0.085854, 0.622686);
    plasmaColormap[85]=vec3(0.610667, 0.090204, 0.619951);
    plasmaColormap[86]=vec3(0.615812, 0.094564, 0.61714);
    plasmaColormap[87]=vec3(0.620919, 0.098934, 0.614257);
    plasmaColormap[88]=vec3(0.625987, 0.103312, 0.611305);
    plasmaColormap[89]=vec3(0.631017, 0.107699, 0.608287);
    plasmaColormap[90]=vec3(0.636008, 0.112092, 0.605205);
    plasmaColormap[91]=vec3(0.640959, 0.116492, 0.602065);
    plasmaColormap[92]=vec3(0.645872, 0.120898, 0.598867);
    plasmaColormap[93]=vec3(0.650746, 0.125309, 0.595617);
    plasmaColormap[94]=vec3(0.65558, 0.129725, 0.592317);
    plasmaColormap[95]=vec3(0.660374, 0.134144, 0.588971);
    plasmaColormap[96]=vec3(0.665129, 0.138566, 0.585582);
    plasmaColormap[97]=vec3(0.669845, 0.142992, 0.582154);
    plasmaColormap[98]=vec3(0.674522, 0.147419, 0.578688);
    plasmaColormap[99]=vec3(0.67916, 0.151848, 0.575189);
    plasmaColormap[100]=vec3(0.683758, 0.156278, 0.57166);
    plasmaColormap[101]=vec3(0.688318, 0.160709, 0.568103);
    plasmaColormap[102]=vec3(0.69284, 0.165141, 0.564522);
    plasmaColormap[103]=vec3(0.697324, 0.169573, 0.560919);
    plasmaColormap[104]=vec3(0.701769, 0.174005, 0.557296);
    plasmaColormap[105]=vec3(0.706178, 0.178437, 0.553657);
    plasmaColormap[106]=vec3(0.710549, 0.182868, 0.550004);
    plasmaColormap[107]=vec3(0.714883, 0.187299, 0.546338);
    plasmaColormap[108]=vec3(0.719181, 0.191729, 0.542663);
    plasmaColormap[109]=vec3(0.723444, 0.196158, 0.538981);
    plasmaColormap[110]=vec3(0.72767, 0.200586, 0.535293);
    plasmaColormap[111]=vec3(0.731862, 0.205013, 0.531601);
    plasmaColormap[112]=vec3(0.736019, 0.209439, 0.527908);
    plasmaColormap[113]=vec3(0.740143, 0.213864, 0.524216);
    plasmaColormap[114]=vec3(0.744232, 0.218288, 0.520524);
    plasmaColormap[115]=vec3(0.748289, 0.222711, 0.516834);
    plasmaColormap[116]=vec3(0.752312, 0.227133, 0.513149);
    plasmaColormap[117]=vec3(0.756304, 0.231555, 0.509468);
    plasmaColormap[118]=vec3(0.760264, 0.235976, 0.505794);
    plasmaColormap[119]=vec3(0.764193, 0.240396, 0.502126);
    plasmaColormap[120]=vec3(0.76809, 0.244817, 0.498465);
    plasmaColormap[121]=vec3(0.771958, 0.249237, 0.494813);
    plasmaColormap[122]=vec3(0.775796, 0.253658, 0.491171);
    plasmaColormap[123]=vec3(0.779604, 0.258078, 0.487539);
    plasmaColormap[124]=vec3(0.783383, 0.2625, 0.483918);
    plasmaColormap[125]=vec3(0.787133, 0.266922, 0.480307);
    plasmaColormap[126]=vec3(0.790855, 0.271345, 0.476706);
    plasmaColormap[127]=vec3(0.794549, 0.27577, 0.473117);
    plasmaColormap[128]=vec3(0.798216, 0.280197, 0.469538);
    plasmaColormap[129]=vec3(0.801855, 0.284626, 0.465971);
    plasmaColormap[130]=vec3(0.805467, 0.289057, 0.462415);
    plasmaColormap[131]=vec3(0.809052, 0.293491, 0.45887);
    plasmaColormap[132]=vec3(0.812612, 0.297928, 0.455338);
    plasmaColormap[133]=vec3(0.816144, 0.302368, 0.451816);
    plasmaColormap[134]=vec3(0.819651, 0.306812, 0.448306);
    plasmaColormap[135]=vec3(0.823132, 0.311261, 0.444806);
    plasmaColormap[136]=vec3(0.826588, 0.315714, 0.441316);
    plasmaColormap[137]=vec3(0.830018, 0.320172, 0.437836);
    plasmaColormap[138]=vec3(0.833422, 0.324635, 0.434366);
    plasmaColormap[139]=vec3(0.836801, 0.329105, 0.430905);
    plasmaColormap[140]=vec3(0.840155, 0.33358, 0.427455);
    plasmaColormap[141]=vec3(0.843484, 0.338062, 0.424013);
    plasmaColormap[142]=vec3(0.846788, 0.342551, 0.420579);
    plasmaColormap[143]=vec3(0.850066, 0.347048, 0.417153);
    plasmaColormap[144]=vec3(0.853319, 0.351553, 0.413734);
    plasmaColormap[145]=vec3(0.856547, 0.356066, 0.410322);
    plasmaColormap[146]=vec3(0.85975, 0.360588, 0.406917);
    plasmaColormap[147]=vec3(0.862927, 0.365119, 0.403519);
    plasmaColormap[148]=vec3(0.866078, 0.36966, 0.400126);
    plasmaColormap[149]=vec3(0.869203, 0.374212, 0.396738);
    plasmaColormap[150]=vec3(0.872303, 0.378774, 0.393355);
    plasmaColormap[151]=vec3(0.875376, 0.383347, 0.389976);
    plasmaColormap[152]=vec3(0.878423, 0.387932, 0.3866);
    plasmaColormap[153]=vec3(0.881443, 0.392529, 0.383229);
    plasmaColormap[154]=vec3(0.884436, 0.397139, 0.37986);
    plasmaColormap[155]=vec3(0.887402, 0.401762, 0.376494);
    plasmaColormap[156]=vec3(0.89034, 0.406398, 0.37313);
    plasmaColormap[157]=vec3(0.89325, 0.411048, 0.369768);
    plasmaColormap[158]=vec3(0.896131, 0.415712, 0.366407);
    plasmaColormap[159]=vec3(0.898984, 0.420392, 0.363047);
    plasmaColormap[160]=vec3(0.901807, 0.425087, 0.359688);
    plasmaColormap[161]=vec3(0.904601, 0.429797, 0.356329);
    plasmaColormap[162]=vec3(0.907365, 0.434524, 0.35297);
    plasmaColormap[163]=vec3(0.910098, 0.439268, 0.34961);
    plasmaColormap[164]=vec3(0.9128, 0.444029, 0.346251);
    plasmaColormap[165]=vec3(0.915471, 0.448807, 0.34289);
    plasmaColormap[166]=vec3(0.918109, 0.453603, 0.339529);
    plasmaColormap[167]=vec3(0.920714, 0.458417, 0.336166);
    plasmaColormap[168]=vec3(0.923287, 0.463251, 0.332801);
    plasmaColormap[169]=vec3(0.925825, 0.468103, 0.329435);
    plasmaColormap[170]=vec3(0.928329, 0.472975, 0.326067);
    plasmaColormap[171]=vec3(0.930798, 0.477867, 0.322697);
    plasmaColormap[172]=vec3(0.933232, 0.48278, 0.319325);
    plasmaColormap[173]=vec3(0.93563, 0.487712, 0.315952);
    plasmaColormap[174]=vec3(0.93799, 0.492667, 0.312575);
    plasmaColormap[175]=vec3(0.940313, 0.497642, 0.309197);
    plasmaColormap[176]=vec3(0.942598, 0.502639, 0.305816);
    plasmaColormap[177]=vec3(0.944844, 0.507658, 0.302433);
    plasmaColormap[178]=vec3(0.947051, 0.512699, 0.299049);
    plasmaColormap[179]=vec3(0.949217, 0.517763, 0.295662);
    plasmaColormap[180]=vec3(0.951344, 0.52285, 0.292275);
    plasmaColormap[181]=vec3(0.953428, 0.52796, 0.288883);
    plasmaColormap[182]=vec3(0.95547, 0.533093, 0.28549);
    plasmaColormap[183]=vec3(0.957469, 0.53825, 0.282096);
    plasmaColormap[184]=vec3(0.959424, 0.543431, 0.278701);
    plasmaColormap[185]=vec3(0.961336, 0.548636, 0.275305);
    plasmaColormap[186]=vec3(0.963203, 0.553865, 0.271909);
    plasmaColormap[187]=vec3(0.965024, 0.559118, 0.268513);
    plasmaColormap[188]=vec3(0.966798, 0.564396, 0.265118);
    plasmaColormap[189]=vec3(0.968526, 0.5697, 0.261721);
    plasmaColormap[190]=vec3(0.970205, 0.575028, 0.258325);
    plasmaColormap[191]=vec3(0.971835, 0.580382, 0.254931);
    plasmaColormap[192]=vec3(0.973416, 0.585761, 0.25154);
    plasmaColormap[193]=vec3(0.974947, 0.591165, 0.248151);
    plasmaColormap[194]=vec3(0.976428, 0.596595, 0.244767);
    plasmaColormap[195]=vec3(0.977856, 0.602051, 0.241387);
    plasmaColormap[196]=vec3(0.979233, 0.607532, 0.238013);
    plasmaColormap[197]=vec3(0.980556, 0.613039, 0.234646);
    plasmaColormap[198]=vec3(0.981826, 0.618572, 0.231287);
    plasmaColormap[199]=vec3(0.983041, 0.624131, 0.227937);
    plasmaColormap[200]=vec3(0.984199, 0.629718, 0.224595);
    plasmaColormap[201]=vec3(0.985301, 0.63533, 0.221265);
    plasmaColormap[202]=vec3(0.986345, 0.640969, 0.217948);
    plasmaColormap[203]=vec3(0.987332, 0.646633, 0.214648);
    plasmaColormap[204]=vec3(0.98826, 0.652325, 0.211364);
    plasmaColormap[205]=vec3(0.989128, 0.658043, 0.2081);
    plasmaColormap[206]=vec3(0.989935, 0.663787, 0.204859);
    plasmaColormap[207]=vec3(0.990681, 0.669558, 0.201642);
    plasmaColormap[208]=vec3(0.991365, 0.675355, 0.198453);
    plasmaColormap[209]=vec3(0.991985, 0.681179, 0.195295);
    plasmaColormap[210]=vec3(0.992541, 0.68703, 0.19217);
    plasmaColormap[211]=vec3(0.993032, 0.692907, 0.189084);
    plasmaColormap[212]=vec3(0.993456, 0.69881, 0.186041);
    plasmaColormap[213]=vec3(0.993814, 0.704741, 0.183043);
    plasmaColormap[214]=vec3(0.994103, 0.710698, 0.180097);
    plasmaColormap[215]=vec3(0.994324, 0.716681, 0.177208);
    plasmaColormap[216]=vec3(0.994474, 0.722691, 0.174381);
    plasmaColormap[217]=vec3(0.994553, 0.728728, 0.171622);
    plasmaColormap[218]=vec3(0.994561, 0.734791, 0.168938);
    plasmaColormap[219]=vec3(0.994495, 0.74088, 0.166335);
    plasmaColormap[220]=vec3(0.994355, 0.746995, 0.163821);
    plasmaColormap[221]=vec3(0.994141, 0.753137, 0.161404);
    plasmaColormap[222]=vec3(0.993851, 0.759304, 0.159092);
    plasmaColormap[223]=vec3(0.993482, 0.765499, 0.156891);
    plasmaColormap[224]=vec3(0.993033, 0.77172, 0.154808);
    plasmaColormap[225]=vec3(0.992505, 0.777967, 0.152855);
    plasmaColormap[226]=vec3(0.991897, 0.784239, 0.151042);
    plasmaColormap[227]=vec3(0.991209, 0.790537, 0.149377);
    plasmaColormap[228]=vec3(0.990439, 0.796859, 0.14787);
    plasmaColormap[229]=vec3(0.989587, 0.803205, 0.146529);
    plasmaColormap[230]=vec3(0.988648, 0.809579, 0.145357);
    plasmaColormap[231]=vec3(0.987621, 0.815978, 0.144363);
    plasmaColormap[232]=vec3(0.986509, 0.822401, 0.143557);
    plasmaColormap[233]=vec3(0.985314, 0.828846, 0.142945);
    plasmaColormap[234]=vec3(0.984031, 0.835315, 0.142528);
    plasmaColormap[235]=vec3(0.982653, 0.841812, 0.142303);
    plasmaColormap[236]=vec3(0.98119, 0.848329, 0.142279);
    plasmaColormap[237]=vec3(0.979644, 0.854866, 0.142453);
    plasmaColormap[238]=vec3(0.977995, 0.861432, 0.142808);
    plasmaColormap[239]=vec3(0.976265, 0.868016, 0.143351);
    plasmaColormap[240]=vec3(0.974443, 0.874622, 0.144061);
    plasmaColormap[241]=vec3(0.97253, 0.88125, 0.144923);
    plasmaColormap[242]=vec3(0.970533, 0.887896, 0.145919);
    plasmaColormap[243]=vec3(0.968443, 0.894564, 0.147014);
    plasmaColormap[244]=vec3(0.966271, 0.901249, 0.14818);
    plasmaColormap[245]=vec3(0.964021, 0.90795, 0.14937);
    plasmaColormap[246]=vec3(0.961681, 0.914672, 0.15052);
    plasmaColormap[247]=vec3(0.959276, 0.921407, 0.151566);
    plasmaColormap[248]=vec3(0.956808, 0.928152, 0.152409);
    plasmaColormap[249]=vec3(0.954287, 0.934908, 0.152921);
    plasmaColormap[250]=vec3(0.951726, 0.941671, 0.152925);
    plasmaColormap[251]=vec3(0.949151, 0.948435, 0.152178);
    plasmaColormap[252]=vec3(0.946602, 0.95519, 0.150328);
    plasmaColormap[253]=vec3(0.944152, 0.961916, 0.146861);
    plasmaColormap[254]=vec3(0.941896, 0.96859, 0.140956);
    plasmaColormap[255]=vec3(0.940015, 0.975158, 0.131326);

  if (computeDiff == 0) // Compute color
    fColor = colorBands == 0 ? vec4(colorOut, 1) : vec4(floor(.5 + colorBands * colorOut) / colorBands, 1);
  else if (computeDiff == 1) // Compute colormapped distance
    fColor = vec4(computePlasmaColormap(diffScaling * computeColorDistance(), plasmaColormap), 1);
  else if (computeDiff == 2) { // Compute distance
    float distance = computeColorDistance();
    float r = floor(distance * 255);
    float g = floor((distance - r / 255) * pow(255, 2));
    float b = floor((distance - r / 255 - g / pow(255, 2)) * pow(255, 3));
    fColor = vec4(r / 255, g / 255, b / 255, 1);
  }

//  colorOut = vec4(0.7, 0.2, 0.3, 1);
}
```

My question is, do you have any suggestions to improve this shader? Maybe I can do something on the variant `plasmaColormap`. I don't really know where to look or what can be optimized here.

Comment: what do you want to optimize for? runtime? How long does it take now? Did you turn on compiler optimizations?

Comment: Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954927/passing-a-list-of-values-to-fragment-shader), it can be passed as a uniform array from your program.

Comment: @code_freak Thanks. But I'm confused. If I put the color map into a buffer and pass it from CPU to GPU, would it be faster? I'm not sure why. The color map is a determined value, Will it make a difference in speed between initializing a color map in GPU and passing a color map from CPU to GPU?

Comment: I would put the `plasmaColormap` into 1D texture ... that way you can be  sure its not initialized for each fragment again and again  on any implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The least you can do is to put the `plasmaColors[256]` into a constant array like this.

```
const vec3 plasmaColormap[256] = vec3[256](
    vec3(0.050383, 0.029803, 0.527975),
    vec3(0.063536, 0.028426, 0.533124),
    ... all the rest of the values
);
```

and change reference in `computePlasmaColormap` function.

The second variant of this is to put the color map into a texture or a uniform buffer as is suggested in the comments.

Hope this clarifies some issues.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm confused about the second variant. If I put the color map into a buffer and pass it from CPU to GPU, would it be faster? I'm not sure why. The color map is a determined value, Will it make a difference in speed between initializing a color map in GPU and passing a color map from CPU to GPU?

Comment: If the colormap is predefined, then there is no use in putting this colormap into buffer. If you want to quickly experiment and change the colormap at runtime, only then it is better to put this colormap into buffer. It is not an "optimization", maybe just a "cleanup" and "generalization" (allowing to modify values at runtime).