# The problem of using TBO to transfer a large amount of one-dimensional byte data to the shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I want to transfer a lot of images loaded by `stb_image` to fragment shader by texture buffer object in OpenGL.

I first merge all the image data (every image file is in RGB format), and use one `unsigned char` pointer named `data` to point to them, this means **all image data are put together in the format of `RGBRGB...`**

Then, I used the following code to send all image data to fragment shader:

```cpp
unsigned tbo, tex;
glGenBuffers(1, &tbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tbo);
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tex);
glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_R8UI, tbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0);
[...]
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tbo);
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, len * sizeof(unsigned char),
            NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW); // len is the length of data
glBufferSubData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0, len * sizeof(unsigned char), data);
```

and in rendering loop:

```cpp
shader.use();
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, tex);
[...]
```

in my fragment shader:

```cpp
layout (binding = 0) uniform samplerBuffer image_texture_buffer;
out vec4 FragColor;
[...]
void main(){
    FragColor = texelFetch(image_texture_buffer, 0);
}
[...]
```

But FragColor is always black.

Edited on 2021/4/3:
I used this function to merge all the image data:

```cpp
void merge_data(unsigned char *res, int lena, unsigned char *data, int lenb) {
    //cout << lena << ' ' << lenb << endl;
    res = (unsigned char *)realloc(res, lena + lenb);
    //strcat_s((char *)res, sizeof data, (char *)data);
    for (int i = lena, j = 0; j < lenb; ++i, ++j) res[i] = data[j];
}
```

In addition, someone told me that the **video memory data** must be **aligned with even numbers**, which means that I must transmit the data to the shader in the format of `RGBARGBA...`, Is this the effect?

Comment: Check for OpenGL errors.

Comment: Have you tried using the other implementations of ```texelFetch``` https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/texelFetch.xhtml

Comment: @vikAy I haven’t tried other texelFetch implementations, but for samplerBuffer, isn’t only `texelFetch(samplerBuffer, int)` available?

Comment: @vikAy The answer with the highest number of approvals on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954927/passing-a-list-of-values-to-fragment-shader) said that `texture buffer` is one-dimensional, so I chose this function( `gvec4 texelFetch(gsampler1D sampler, int P,int lod);`) to got pixels on the picture.

Comment: @yys_c: It specifically says "Though they are one-dimensional, ***they are not 1D textures.***"

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm sorry for not reading it carefully. I did see that it is not a one-dimensional texture, but what function is needed to get the data in the texture buffer?(I saw [this example](https://gist.github.com/roxlu/5090067) before, which puzzled me)